# Huygens' principle for diffraction through an apeture

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, multiple-integral, electromagnetism

I understand that integrals are analogous to summing for continuous values, but for some reason I am still terrible at modeling continuous phenomena. Take for example calculating the diffraction of a wave traveling through the apeture shown below.

[image]

The book that I am following states that the amplitutde of a spherical wave moving away from the origin is

$$ u(x,y) = A \frac{e^{i (k r- \omega t)}}{r} $$

therefore, using Huygens’ principle with a plane wave incident normally on the aperture shown in the figure, the optical disturbance at $P_2$ is the sum of spherical waves emanating from the aperture:

$$ u(x,y) = A e^{-i \omega t} \iint_{a} \frac{e^{i k r_{12}}}{r_{12}} dx_a dy_a$$

where the integral is over the apeture area.

Now imagine that we discretized the problem so that the electric field at a point in the imaging plane is given by the sum of many spherical sources in the apeture plane:

$$ A e^{-i \omega t} \sum_i^M \sum_j^N \frac{e^{i k \sqrt{(x - x_{a_i})^2 + (y - y_{a_j})^2 + z^2} }}{\sqrt{(x - x_{a_i})^2 + (y - y_{a_j})^2 + z^2}} $$

How do we smooth out this sum? Typically we would have something of the form $\sum f(x_i) \Delta x \rightarrow \int f(x) dx$, so how do the $dx_a$ and $dy_a$ appear?

Comment: Your sumands need a "small" area $\Delta a_{i,j}=\Delta x_i\,\Delta y_j$.

Comment: @Mark Viola Isn't this an ad hoc justification? For example, if I have a million point-charge particles, I just sum the e-fields of each to get the total electric field. No need to introduce deltas. So if I have a million spherical sources, don't I just sum them?

Comment: You need to weight the sources appropriately.  If you begin with a surface source density $\sigma$, then those "million point charge particles" $q_i$ have discretization $q_i=\sigma_i \,\Delta a_i$.

Comment: As I was eating breakfast this morning I literally thought of this. Thanks though!

Comment: Of course.  My pleasure.